# JSON Decoding issue using Requests in python 2.7.10 for Zendesk API

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-requests, zendesk

I have a python script that I am using to call to the Zendesk API in order to get back a JSON return.  The typical `Data = response.json()` worked until I had to port everything over to python 2.7.  It worked fine in 3.4.  I tried various different encoding and decoding strategies, and I have gotten it past the break, but then it is in a form I can use.  I need to be able to access the json parts by string, not integer `Data['users']` as an example.  Here is the code I have up to the break.

```
import datetime
import time
import calendar
import requests
import os.path as path
import json
import logging
import Query2UploadRouter
import sys
from httplib import BadStatusLine
from io import open


def byteify(input):

    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {byteify(key):byteify(value) for key,value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [byteify(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input

def runQuery(endPoint,tableName,topJsonTier,userName,passWord,schema,verticaName,verticaPassword,i):

    if path.isfile('Data_Aquisition_Log_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.txt') == True:
        logging.basicConfig(filename='Data_Aquisition_Log_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.txt', filemode='a', level=logging.DEBUG)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(filename='Data_Aquisition_Log_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.txt', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)

    startTime = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()) - 3600

    url = "https://myURL.zendesk.com/api/v2/" + str(endPoint) + str(startTime)

    user = userName
    pwd = passWord
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    # Create a requests to avoid flooding the server with requests
    # Do all of this stuff and then do it again as long as the response JSON has a next page
    while True:

        # Do the HTTP get request

        for x in xrange(0,9):

            logging.debug('Query Attempt...' + str(x))

            try:

                logging.debug(url)
                response = requests.get(url, auth=(user,passWord))
                break

            except:

                err = sys.exc_info()[0]
                logging.debug('There was an error when attemtping to execute the query!  URL: ' + str(url) + ' Error: ' + str(err))
                time.sleep(5)
                pass

        # Check for HTTP codes other than 200
        if response.status_code != 200 or response.status_code is None:
            if response.status_code == 429:
                logging.debug(unicode(response.status_code) + 'Rate Limited.  Waiting to Retry')
                time.sleep(float(response.headers['retry-after']))
                response = requests.get(url, auth=(user,passWord))
            elif response.status_code == 422:
                logging.debug( 'The last record was reached')
                break
            else:
                logging.debug('Problem with the request. Retrying.')
                response = requests.get(url, auth=(user,passWord))

        # Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data

        data = byteify(response.json())
```

Using the biteify was a solution I found online that was my most recent attempt.  Here was the error response I got back:

```
DEBUG:root:Starting run for ZendeskUsersTest!!
DEBUG:root:Query Attempt... 0 
DEBUG:root:https://myURL.zendesk.com/api/v2/incremental/users.json?start_time=1434444644
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): .zendesk.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /api/v2/incremental/users.json?start_time=1434444644 HTTP/1.1" 200 None 
DEBUG:root:An error caused the run to break! <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
No JSON object could be decoded
DEBUG:root:All data aquisition was completed!
```

So as you can see I'm getting a 200 response.  Putting in the URL directly into a web page gives me that JSON return and I validated it using JSONlint.

Comment: What is in `response.content` and `response.headers`?

Comment: The content is a full json return.  Looking at the headers I did find something that could be causing my problem `'content-encoding': 'gzip'` I'll try to get the full header return in a bit.

Comment: Content-encoding compression is handled transparently; you'd not be able to see the `.content` data otherwise. It is not the cause of any problems; the content *itself* is the issue here. Is there a `Content-Type` header? Can you share the `.content` value at all?

Comment: Content type is `'application/json; charset=UTF-8'  the .content is a properly formatted json return. I can use just response.content, or json.dumps(response.content) without issue, but the I cannot search by string g indices, only numeric.

Comment: `json.dumps(response.content)` creates a double-encoded JSON string, that'll work with *any* string. Did you mean `json.loads(response.content)` instead?

Comment: Using `json.loads(response.content)` throws a `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: So the response has problems still. I'll ask again: *Can you share it*.

Comment: `{"id":123456789,"url":"https://myURL.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/10987654321.json","name":"SomeName","email":"someemail@email.com","verified":false,"external_id":null,"tags":[],"alias":null,"active":true,"shared":false,"shared_agent":false,"signature":null,"details":null,"notes":null,"custom_role_id":null,"moderator":false,"suspended":false,"chat_only":false,"user_fields":{}}`

Comment: This is just an example of 1 of the 1000+ users that I am getting back.  Is the issue the double quotes?  should it be something more like `"id":"123456789"`

Comment: No, the format is correct for JSON. Can you share the `print(repr(response.content))` output? Without a complete python representation this is impossible to debug otherwise.